# Which clustering algorithm shall I use?

Tags: clustering, spatio-temporal, real-time

I need some help
My project aims to develop algorithms for spatial temporal analysis of Flickr, Twitter and Foursquare databases to detect any kind of significant changes, named as “Event” in real time. Event can be defined as any anomalous user activity, which happens at a time or within a specific period of time. For this, different clustering methods should be implemented and the best fit has to be selected. The detected events will be visualized for further exploration.

This information will be integrated with some other VGI sources to provide a series of Volunteered Geographic services.

Could you please suggest me which clustering algorithm is good for this project? And also please suggest me some books and study material...

Answer (score 2):

You will have to try out a lot of algorithms.

There is no general rule of what works for your data.

In fact it seems you don't really know yet what your data looks like yourself... first get your data, then *visualize* it, then figure out what to do next. You can't solve a problem which you have not seen yet.